# Discord.py: Join and leave messages are not working

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Creating a join and leave message functions for when people join and leave my server, but it doesn't seem to be functioning and the code looks completely fine. No errors. Is there something I'm missing?

```
# are any of these causing the issues?
intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

client.remove_command('help')

client.load_extension('cogs.commands')
# ---------


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    await client.wait_until_ready()

    channel = client.get_channel(850882992708124702)

    await channel.send(f"Welcome {member}!")


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):

    channel = client.get_channel(850883012103241748)

    await channel.send(f"Goodbye {member}!")
```

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński , No that did not fix the problem. Nothing happened.

Comment: Try adding some debugging print statements right after the function definition.

Comment: I actually had them before. They never appeared. I had it print `print("Member has joined")` but it never printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you overwrite your client:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
```

Use this to fix that issue:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)
```

Comment: That completely fixed it. I didn't even realize I was doing that lol what a an overlook. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It took me a while as well, It's easy to miss. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use too much `client`
For this problem, this is your original code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
client.remove_command('help')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands')
```

To fix it, you must include `command_prefix='-'` with `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`
So here's the code for how to fix it:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

client.remove_command('help')
client.load_extension('cogs.commands')
```